# video is playing with many extra rectangle doted over the video

Tags: android, media-player

[image: It can be easily view]

It can be easily view the doted rectangle over the video, so, please suggest how to get rid of these issue.. thank you for your concern

Comment: That's excellent. Can you share your solution with us, possibly by writing an answer and accepting your own answer? Thank you.

Comment: today I post these question.. so, still working on.. if u think so, then vote the question to make it popular... so, that it can be optimized by many developer..